# Conexão Banco de dados Progress pelo PHP (framework Laravel), PDO

Tags: php, banco-de-dados, laravel, pdo, progress-bar

estou precisando conectar em um banco Progress via php estou utilizando o framework laravel 5.2 porem o mesmo segundo a documentação só tem suporte aos bancos de dados MySQL, Postgres, SQLite e SQL Server.

Pesquisando encontrei muito pouco sobre como conectar com esse DB através do PHP uma das poucas coisas que encontrei foi sobre como conectar através do PDO então fiz o código abaixo.

```
    $dsn = 'odbc:host=xxx.xx.xxx.x;dbname=minhabase;port=99999DataSource:minhadatasource;';
    $user = 'usuario';
    $password = 'minhasenha';

    $pdo = new \PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
```

Alteração php.ini (habilitar Pdo_odbc)

```
extension=php_pdo_odbc.dll
```

com o código acima aparece o seguinte erro 
PDOException in PaginasController.php line 36:

SQLSTATE[IM002] SQLDriverConnect: 0 [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Nome da fonte de dados não encontrado e nenhum driver padrão especificado

Alguem tem alguma dica de como resolver? ou alguém já fez conexão com esse db através do php

Comment: Isso aí não é postgres, é odbc.

Comment: Amigão, antes de tentar fazer gambiarra no Laravel e usar o PDO diretão, procure uma library para laravel que dê suporte. Vejo muitos programadores querendo usar uma instância PDO no Laravel, sendo que ele já tem o ORM próprio. Nesse caso, eu diria que era melhor nem usar framework.

Comment: Não é só trocar a string do banco em um arquivo(se não me engano o database.php) ?

Comment: Baseando no comentário do @rray, você pode colocar isso [aqui](https://github.com/TobyMaxham/laravel-odbc-driver)

Comment: Isso ai não é uma tecnologia chamada progress (4GL) que utiliza banco de dados SQL Server? Você não está confundindo um tipo de tecnologia integrada com banco de dados não?

Comment: @MiguelBatista poisé nunca tinha ouvido falar de progress como database mas perguntei para o profissional que tenho contato para realizar essa integração e ele me respondeu assim ´banco e progress compatível com o padrão sql-92´

Comment: Já deu uma olhada no tópico: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30480385/laravel-5-with-postgres-sql ?

Answer (score -1):

Como você disse que já escolheu banco de dados padrão como Postgres SQL

```
'Default' => 'pgsql',
```

Você precisa obrigatóriamente descomentar as linhas que chamam as extensões pdo e postgres no seu php (php.ini)

Ou seja, você precisa descomentar as seguintes linhas em seu php.ini

```
Extension = pdo_pgsql.so
Extension = pgsql.so
```

Nota :

Não se esqueça de parar e iniciar o seu apache depois de fazer isso muda.

Comment: Progress != postgreSQL